# What to consider when choosing between an internal or external hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive

I need to buy another hard drive.  The question is, internal or external?  How do I choose between the two?  What are the advantages/disadvantages of one over the other?

Comment: What is the drive going to be used for?

Comment: I'm going to store lots of media on it, mostly video, and I'll be watching those videos.  I might also install games on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simply, if you need it for storage, on a fixed PC, and are unlikely to need to use it outside your lan, go for an internal disk. If its gonna be going on walkabout, external disk. The internals are the same, but internal disks mostly use PATA or SATA, while external ones for most part use the slower USB interface, or ESATA, though the latter is not as common, and just sata.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, you want your external drive as a backup drive. Of course, this is all down to personal preference, but in general... go internal, unless it's a backup or rarely accesssed drive.

Otherwise, if it's a drive that you access frequently but for some reason move for place to place, use an external drive (though in this case there are probably better solutions)

In a nutshell, **you want an internal drive unless you are using it as a backup drive - in which case, it makes little difference**.

It depends upon your *specific* needs. What exactly do you want this drive for?

Answer (score 1):

Store media mostly video : **external**.

Install games (or any other non-portable product) : **only internal**.